# Show which workspaces have applications on openbox

Tags: openbox, workspaces

I run openbox on debian, and I have 49 workspaces, and use the [setlayout](http://openbox.org/dist/tools/setlayout.c) command to have them put in a square instead of a line.

I also have keyboard shortcuts to navigate around the workspaces. When I navigate around, the thing below appears in the middle of my screen showing me which workspace I'm in.

[image: Desktop selector]

My question is, can I have the squares on the thing above have some visual indicator, like a different color when there's a window in the workspace?